Son kills a child during a Middle Eastern conflict, sends photo to his father
So I remember seeing a movie quite some years ago but I can't find its title. It revolves around some photos that a soldier took and sent back to his father. The photos revealed that his son's armored convoy (during some Middle Eastern conflict) didn't slow down when they saw a child on the road and hit him, and the son took a photo of the deceased child. It might have involved a government cover-up/conspiracy, but I can't tell for sure.
I vaguely remember that the father was trying to find out the truth (because his son was dead or something like that). The main plot happens somewhere in the civilized world, and the scenes from the Middle East appear in flashbacks/narrations (Gulf War, Iraq, something like that).
English live action, could've seen it 10-12 years ago on a local channel with Romanian subtitles.

Welcome to the community. A convoy has many drivers. Was the son a driver that hit the child? That is the only way he himself would have been "responsible" for the accident. I hope you like it here.

I think the son was driving a Humvee or MRAP, either alone or as part of a convoy, and his CO, sitting next to him, ordered him to keep going when the child was on the road, because it could be a trap.

In the Valley of Elah

A retired military investigator works with a police detective to
  uncover the truth behind his son's disappearance following his return
  from a tour of duty in Iraq.

Trailer:



Tommy Lee Jones plays the ex-military father who tries to find out what happened to his son after he returned from Iraq.
You can watch the movie here:




Ladies and gentleman, we have a winner! Many thanks to everyone, can't wait to watch the movie. I am certainly going to get involved in this marvelous community!
